# How to maneuver between two divs using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying the following:

```
<header>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
</header>
<nav class="top-navigation">
    <ul class="top-menu">
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Where my CSS is like below:

```
.top-menu{
    display: none;
}
.menu-toggle:checked .top-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

But I'm failing to do that. I also tried:

```
.menu-toggle:checked ~ .top-menu
```

But failed too.

I can make it work if I can place `input[checkbox]` within `<nav>`. But actually for templating purpose I need to place it like above HTML (separated from each other).

How can I do that? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: With this HTML structure it's not possible with `:checked`. Checkbox needs to be at least outside of `header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BhojendraSah for his answer. It's, to me, is saying: *sorry, it's not possible* - as what already said by @dsfq in the comment:

> *With this HTML structure it's not possible with `:checked`. Checkbox needs to be at least outside of `header`.*

But I already said, I can't change my template to make 'em in a single container. But what I've got that without this, it's impossible.

So I decided to do the plan B:

```
 <nav class="top-navigation">
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
    <ul class="top-menu">
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And do some extra floating and margin staff:

```
.menu-toggle{
   float: right;
   margin-top: -35px; /* as per my template */
   margin-right: 20px; /* as per my template */
}
```

to make the feel that the checkbox is within the `<header>`. With much thanks, I'm not accepting Bhojendra's answer, because I already said, I actually can't go for something like that now. Thanks Bhojendra.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your nav inside header like this:

```
<header>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
    <nav class="top-navigation">
       <ul class="top-menu">
           <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And only you'll be able to use:

```
.top-menu{
    display: none;
}
.menu-toggle:checked + .top-navigation .top-menu{
    display: block;
}
```

```css
.top-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .menu-toggle:checked + .top-navigation .top-menu{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<header>
        <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
        <nav class="top-navigation">
           <ul class="top-menu">
               <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```